# Need to prevent Listview Row from always being 100% width of Listview

Tags: android, listview

**Goal**

I want the Listview, in an activity, to fill the width of the screen (so that the listview scroller appears against the edge of the screen).

I then want the listview Row to not fill 100% of the width. For example, I want it just 400dp wide.

**Problem**

The Listview Row is ALWAYS taking up 100% of the listview's width - even though the width is supposed to be 400dp.

**XML of the Main Listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Envelope"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/prompt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:divider="#00FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="7dip"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML of the Listview's Row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/label1"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                      android:paddingLeft="20dip"             
                      android:paddingRight="10dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/label2"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="0"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                      android:paddingLeft="10dip"             
                      android:paddingRight="10dip"/>

            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" 
                      android:layout_width="34dip" 
                      android:layout_height="34dip"
                      android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                      android:duplicateParentState="true"
                      android:button="@drawable/checkbox_states"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result with that XML is that the "row" linearlayout fills 100% of the width of the listview even though I would expect only 400dp to be used. I've spent 4 hours on trying to get it right /frustrated

Comment: Can you show the getView() method of your adapter? Somehow your layout properties are getting ignored when your row view is inflated. However, Mikael Olsson's solution is likely preferable so your layout will work on any size device. But that solution still relies on your layout params from XML working.

Comment: Are you sure your device/emulator width is more than 400dp? Also can you explain why you want to do this because it doesn't sound like a good approach.

Comment: this problem exists purely out of style - the listview's scroller needs to be against the border of the screen. I checked the adapter but that just inflates the XML without making any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `android:layout_width="400dp"`

Try using `weightSum` and `weight` in the following way:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textEmp_id"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                          android:paddingLeft="20dip"             
                          android:paddingRight="10dip" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/label2"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                          android:paddingLeft="10dip"             
                          android:paddingRight="10dip"/>

                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" 
                          android:layout_width="34dip" 
                          android:layout_height="34dip"
                          android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                          android:duplicateParentState="true"
                          android:button="@drawable/checkbox_states"/>


        </LinearLayout>
         <View
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this as follows: Specified the ListView to fill the entire width of the display. Then specified the row's layout to be 400dp wide as well as `weightSum="1"`. Each view within the row's layout was then  assigned a `layout_weight`. Unfortunately, the result was the same: the row filled the entire width of the ListView :-(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to set the ListView Row to match it's parent. 
You can't always assume the available width is 400dp. Also
set a left and right margin to get some space.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"      
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

Comment: yeah, that's one option but on xlarge screens the width will get disgustingly wide (I wish there existed a `layout_max_width` parameter for views!). The XML I showed above is going to run on "large" layout devices so there will always be 400dp of space available.

Comment: Perhaps the problem occur because you set label1 to match_parent and then checkbox width to 34 dip on top of that.

Comment: Thanks for that idea; I changed the textbox to `wrap_content` but it didn't affect the layout. I checked the UI with a UI-Dump in DDMS and the listview bounds are [13,413] to [787,1185]. A "row" LinearLayout bounds are [13,413] to [787,480]. And the innermost LinearLayout is [22,420] to [555,465]. It makes no sense !!

Comment: I believe ListViews are meant to go from left to right screen edge. I can't recall I've ever seen a listview being centered. If you want something more tablet friendly then you probably need to go for a ListFragment.